# What is causing the spacing around these QLabels?

Tags: python, pyqt

There is an unusual spacing around these labels, I have added a red border to better visualize everything

It current looks like this:

[image]

But I would like it to look like *this*:

[image]

As you can see, the two "LED" labels, which have been set with pixmap from images, have excess spacing on the top and bottom despite the fact that nothing has set them to be this way.

```
class QtLed(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, color=None):

        self.ledIcon = QLabel()
        self.ledIcon.setObjectName('ledIcon')

        self.changeColor(color)

        QWidget.__init__(self)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.ledIcon)

     def changeColor(self, color):

        pixmap = QPixmap('img/offLED.png')
        if color == "green":
            pixmap = QPixmap('img/greenLED.png')
        if color == "red":
            pixmap = QPixmap('img/redLED.png')
        pixmap = pixmap.scaled(15, 15, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

        self.ledIcon.setPixmap(pixmap)


class BOX(QWidget):
    mode = None
    connected = False

    def __init__(self, BOXnum):

        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ID = BOXnum

        self.frame = QGroupBox()
        self.frame.setTitle('BOX' + str(self.ID))

        BOXcontent = QVBoxLayout()
        BOXcontent.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.frame.setLayout(BOXcontent)

        modeBox = QHBoxLayout()
        modeBox.setObjectName('modeBox')
        SWlabel = QLabel("SW")
        HWlabel = QLabel("HW")
        SWlabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter);
        HWlabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter);
        modeBox.addWidget(SWlabel)
        modeBox.addWidget(HWlabel)
        BOXcontent.addLayout(modeBox)

        ledBox = QHBoxLayout()
        ledBox.setObjectName('ledBox')
        self.led1 = QtLed("green")
        self.led2 = QtLed("red")
        ledBox.addWidget(self.led1)
        ledBox.addWidget(self.led2)
        BOXcontent.addLayout(ledBox)

        configButton = QPushButton("Config")
        BOXcontent.addWidget(configButton)

        powerButton = QPushButton("Start")
        BOXcontent.addWidget(powerButton)
```

I've tried adding a global `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;` to every widget, which also didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: try with: `self.ledIcon.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` `lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` on QtLed `__init__`

Comment: This seemed to fix it, but what is lay?

Comment: `lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.ledIcon)`

Comment: ah I'm an idiot, that was supposed to say layout, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying my `QtLed` object's `__init__` to include the below lines seemed to give me the behavior I was wanting. Thanks to @eyllanesc for the answer.

```py
self.ledIcon.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
self.ledIcon.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Do not add irrelevant information in your question as it is considered noise.